# isHidden function requires me to click twice when applying responsive display

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have been using the ishidden function for a while and it works fine with my site;

```
 <script>
function isHidden(oDiv){
  var vDiv = document.getElementById(oDiv);
  vDiv.style.display = (vDiv.style.display == 'none')?'block':'none';
}
```

The functional html code looks like this;

```
<div style="display: true;" style="cursor: hand;" onclick="isHidden('excerpt105')"><span class="opinion-title3">title</span></div><div id="excerpt105" style="display: true;"><span class="opinion-content">Here is a paragraph.</span></div>
```

And it looks like this in page(it's a Chinese site);

[The display of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HTi2.jpg)

Later I put some @media tag into css file try to achieve the following goal: hide every paragraphs(marked in the pic above) when the page size is under 768px; and show them the opposite.Here is my css code;

```
@media(max-width:768px){
.opinion-display {display: none;}
.opinion-tip-display {display: true;} }

@media(min-width:769px){
.opinion-display {display: true;}
.opinion-tip-display {display: none;} }
```

.opinion-display is the class I use to serve my purpose, which works good regarding the "show and hide" part.

And the renewed html code looks like this;

```
<div style="display: true;" class="cursor: hand;" onclick="isHidden('excerpt105')"><span class="opinion-title3">title</span></div><div id="excerpt105" class="opinion-display"><span class="opinion-content">Here is a paragraph.</span></div>
```

The problem is, when the page size is under 768px and all paragraphs are hidden, it requires me to click twice on any of those titles to show those paragraphs back. This never happened before I put on this @media attribute.

Please help guys...

Answer (score 1):

You removed your inline style so `vDiv.style.display` does not have any value for the first time

So when this code is run:

```
  vDiv.style.display = (vDiv.style.display == 'none')?'block':'none';
```

for **first** time `display` is equal `undefined` so expression evaluates to `'none'` and when you click **second** time it is finally `'none'` so it can be changed to `'block'`

You could do following in your function:

```
 vDiv.style.display = (!vDiv.style.display || vDiv.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Also `display:true;` is invalid css.

**Edit**: above solution takes into account only element's inline style attribute which may be empty and style for the element is taken for example from external style sheet. Because of this empty `style.display` cannot be treated the same as `display:none` - it will not work when element is initially visible.

To solve it it is necessary to check [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)   of element:

```
  var vDiv = document.getElementById(oDiv);
  var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(vDiv);
  vDiv.style.display = (elementStyle.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4yncvqn/)

Comment: Good answer, just note that this toggle assumes the display is indeed `display: block`. Divs are by default `display: block` but they could be set otherwise so the best idea is to create two functions to toggle once for when the display is `block` and once when it's `inline`, `inline-block` and so on...

Comment: Thank you Lukbl. When I applied your code, the situation change to the opposite: It worked fine when page size under 768px("display: none" in css) but required two clicks when over 768px("display: block").  Maybe Narxx got the point of creating two functions? Could you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid css property value

```
.opinion-tip-display {display: true;}
.opinion-display {display: true;}
```

It should be

```
.opinion-tip-display {display: block;}
.opinion-display {display: blcck;}
```